# SQL - get specific text from string

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I have column with this strings:

```
['autre__renvoi_vers_un_mail', 'contact_type__email']
['contact_type__email', 'internal__shop', 'uk']
```

I need to get from the string ONLY the `contact_type__*` part (appears only once in each row)

```
contact_type__email
contact_type__email
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [regexp function `regexp_extract()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators?hl=en#regexp_extract), like:

```
regexp_extract(mycol, 'contact_type__[a-zA-Z0-9_]*')
```

This will match on string `'contact_type__` followed by a sequence of letters, numbers, or underscore (which are commonly defined as *word characters*).

Comment: @OksanaOk: welcome! Just to check, what if you use `\\w` instead of `\w`?

Answer (score 0):

Given this example:

```
create table t (col varchar(100));
insert into t values
('[''autre__renvoi_vers_un_mail'', ''contact_type__email'']'),
('[''contact_type__email'', ''internal__shop'', ''uk'']');
```

You can use:

```
select
    substring 
    (
     col,
     charindex('contact_type', col) + 14,
     charindex('''', col, charindex('contact_type', col)) - charindex('contact_type', col) - 14
    )
from
    t;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=859828affe8a9fcd235c186a3afdb1d7)*